# Retrieve JSON data with its values being updated

Tags: java, json, http

I'm really new into using java for fetching java from web and I have come into an issue. I'm parsing the JSON from a website ([Flightradar24.com](https://data-cloud.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?faa=1&bounds=62.593%2C-4.304%2C-48.78%2C47.02&satellite=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&maxage=14400&gliders=1&selected=2c0a3a2a&ems=1&stats=1)) and I'm saving the data from JSON into a CSV file. However the values in the JSON are being updated from time to time, so whenever I'm trying to parse the JSON file again, the updated values are not saved. For example if I have this entry

```
"2c55bbec":["A05F66",29.39,33.43,287,47000,450,"","F OETB1","GLF5","N123FT",1655825174,"DIA","STN","",0,0,"N123FT",0,""]
```

I want to get the updated, which would be this:

```
"2c55bbec":["A05F66",30.07,31.43,306,47000,445,"","F-HECA2","GLF5","N123FT",1655826084,"DIA","STN","",0,64,"N123FT",0,""]
```

However, the only thing I'm able to do is to get the same entry over and over again, without updated values. I'm use Thread.sleep() in order to get the delay, but I get no result.

```
try {
            if(cache.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    if(obj == null){
                        retrieveObject();
                        lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }else{
                        long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long elapsedTimestamp = currentTimestamp - lastTimestamp;
                        long sleep = sleepTime - elapsedTimestamp;
                        if(sleep > 0){
                            Thread.sleep(sleep);
                        }
                        retrieveObject();
                        lastTimestamp = currentTimestamp;
                    }
                    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
                        String flightID = entry.getKey().toString();
                        JsonArray value = (JsonArray) entry.getValue();
                        String[] data = new String[20];
                        for(int i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++){
                            data[i] = value.get(i).toString();
                        }
                        data[19] = flightID;
                        cache.push(data);
                        writeToCSV(data);
                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return true;
```

This is the part of my code where I'm trying to get the updated values (with no results of course) . I'm using HttpURLConnection and BufferedReader in order to read the JSON file from the web.

Is there any way I can get the JSON entries with updated values?
Thank you in advance

**EDITED**

```
URL url = new URL(settings[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Where setting[0] is just the url.

The part of connection where I parse the JSON object

```
int status = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (status > 299) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
            while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(nextLine);
            }
        } else {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(nextLine);
                _processedCNTR++;
            }

            element = gson.fromJson(content.toString(), JsonElement.class);
            obj = element.getAsJsonObject();

            //Step2 connectToSource() returns JSONObject

            obj.remove("stats");
            obj.remove("full_count");
            obj.remove("version");
            obj.remove("selected-aircraft");
            obj.remove("selected");
```

The code of writing the CSV file:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("results.csv",true);
            String s = Arrays.toString(data);
            s = s.replace("]","").replace("[","");
            writer.write(s + "\n");
            writer.close();
```

The part of code where I create the connection:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is your `writeToCSV()` method isn't overwriting the file. You could try to figure out why that's happening and fix it, or you could delete and recreate the file before writing to it again.

Comment: Hello, I just updated the code with the writing of the CSV, if that might help. Thank you